# Type check not working

Tags: javascript, error-handling, typechecking

```
Object.prototype.search = function() {

    if (!(Array.isArray(this) || typeof this === 'object' || this === 'undefined')) {

        throw {
            number: 1,
            err: 'test error'
        }
    }

    var count = 0

    for (item in this) {

        if (typeof this[item] !== 'undefined' || (typeof this[item] !== 'string' && typeof this[item] !== 'number' ) ){
            count++
        }
    }

    return count - 1

}

array1 = ['x', , , 'x', , , 'x', 1, , , , , , 7, 8]

try {

    console.log(array2.search())
}

catch (e) {

    console.log('error ' + e.number)
}
```

Yes i know array2 doesnt exist

Returning 'error undefined'
Typechecking non existant array2 object is not triggering the throw?

How can i catch the error in the prototype method?

Comment: When you were asking your question, there was a big orange **How to Format** box to the right of the text area with useful information in it. There was also an entire toolbar of formatting aids. And a **[?]** button giving formatting help. *And* a preview area located between the text area and the Post Your Question button (so that you'd have to scroll past it to find the button, to encourage you to look at it) showing what your post would look like when posted. Making your post clear, and demonstrating that you took the time to do so, improves your chances of getting good answers.

Comment: This is your fourth question. You should be doing formatting correctly by now.

Comment: Separately: ***Never*** add an enumerable property to `Object.prototype`, and `array2.search()` will throw a `ReferenceError` as `array2` is an undeclared identifier. There's also an extra `}` at the end of the code. Finally: `for-in` is not the correct way to loop an arrays contents.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder  can you tell me why my answer is wrong and give me downvote?

Comment: if coder has no reason then please don't downvote, if you then you must give us reason why do you downvote?

Comment: @Dipakchavda: Why do you think it was me who downvoted? Never assume you know. People comment, people downvote, and they are frequently not the same people. But looking at your answer, probably it's because simple typos don't need *answers*, just comments and close-votes.

Comment: @Dipakchavda: *"if you then you must give us reason why do you downvote"* No, no one is under any obligation whatsoever to explain a downvote (or upvote) to you, at any time, for any reason. The full explanation you are entitled to is on the downvote button tooltip.

Comment: but it is wrong about that person has no reason to downvote

Comment: I saw that some users have even no ability to post a question and description of a question.

Comment: @Dipakchavda: *"but it is wrong about that person has no reason to downvote"* Sure they do. If they think answering a typo question rather than voting to close it (which is what one is supposed to do) is "not useful," which is the only criterion for downvoting. If your post is downvoted, do what I do: Look at it again, critically, and see why someone may have found it unuseful. Look at the overall situation as well. And if you can't think of a reason, shrug and move on. Separately: https://www.xkcd.com/386/

Comment: Thank you, my friend @T.J.Crowder sorry for my obligations.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder sorry im on a mobile

Comment: I subsequently added type checking for the for in loop to check its not counting prototype artifacts.. but my question here is specifically how to throw the error caused by calling my prototype method on an undefined object/array

Comment: I thought this was a coding forum not an anger management forum?

Answer (score 0):

You should replace array2 with array1.

```js
Object.prototype.search = function() {
  if (!Array.isArray(this) || typeof this === 'object' || this === undefined) {
    throw {
      number: 1,
      err: 'test error'
    }
  }
  var count = 0
  for (item in this) {
    if (typeof this[item] !== undefined) {
      count++
    }
  }
  return count - 1
}

array1 = ['x', , , 'x', , , 'x', 1, , , , , , 7, 8];
try {
  console.log(array1.search());
} catch (e) {
  console.log('error ' + e.number)
}
```

Comment: what is the reason to downvote can anyone explain me, if downvote person has the reason?

Comment: Probably someone who downvoted the question because of the bad way it is formed and then they get mad when there are actual good people who just look at the question and help (yes, there are still kids like that out there...). Anyway I think your answer is most correct and shouldn't receive these random downvotes, upvote from me and keep helping people.

Comment: @mrdeadsven thank you but you know people here even not give an answer that why they downvote. I really don't understand why people give downvote without any reason. If the user gives his negative marking to an answer no issue, but at least feedback may remain scope of improvement for next time.

Comment: indeed welcome to the internet where everyone is mad for no reason and just does thing to annoy you. Anyway don't let it bother you to much, seems like it is a random person who's downvoting everyone for no reason. It happens and it is sad but not much you can do about it. As long as you know you helped someone with your answer all should be okay :).

Comment: I totally agree with you Dipak.. surely the purpose of this forum is to give assistance not to discourage people who are learning

Answer (score 0):

It is returning `error undefined` because you are creating an array called `array1` but using your `search` function on an undefined variable called `array2`.

Comment: I don't think so any wrong description so I gave my vote to you, but you should add code so others will find the better reference.

Comment: I know its the wrong array thats why its supposed to throw an error